# v-if="this.canupdate == true" not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In vue I have a property this.canupdate.
My code looks like

```
<template v-if="this.canupdate == true">
                                    <template v-if="row.item.edit">
                                        <b-button variant="success" size="sm" @click="saveprestatierij(row.item, row.index)">
                                            <i class="fas fa-save"></i>
                                        </b-button>
                                    </template>
                                    <template v-else>
                                        <b-button variant="primary" size="sm" @click="toggleeditprestatierij(row.item)">
                                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                        </b-button>
                                    </template>
                                </template>
```

But when I run the code, the block is not displaying, even if this.canupdate has a true value.
Anybody who sees where I'm wrong?

Kind regards,
Tim

Comment: Remove `this` in a template.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `this` from if-statement:

```
<template v-if="canupdate === true">
```

Or you can write like this:

```
<template v-if="canupdate">
```